# OpenVPN is not resolving HTTP/s requests - Can't reach AWS private API Gateway's endpoint when connected to an authorized VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, endpoint, openvpn

OpenVPN is not resolving HTTP/s correctly.

I created a private API gateway to which I want to access through a privated DNS configured in an `execute-api` Endpoint created in the same VPC as the API Gateway.

I can reach it from other resources created in the same VPC. But I want my clients to reach it also, only being connected to my VPN `OpenVPN server`, but they are not able to.

However the `OpenVPN server` is able to reach the API, but the clients are not.

What I think is failing here, is that OpenVPN Server is not redirecting HTTP/s requests correctly as it does for SSH connections.

For SSH connections, the VPN is working perfectly.

This is probably caused because of some missing config. in OpenVPN server or client.

Any idea please?

Appreciated any help.

Kind regards,

Rshad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got resolved.

The problem was that OpenVPN server was not able to push the DNS configuration and though the API endpoint hostname was not resolved.

On the following, we describe the essential steps and issues we followed to solve this issue.

**1. VPC DNS issue**

Regardless of the issue of `OpenVPN` DNS forwarding to the client, we wanted to use the VPC DNS manually, I mean setting it ourselves in the configuration file `/etc/resolv.conf` as follows:

```sh
nameserver <VPC DNS>
<default interface>
```

We tried to set the DNS associated with our VPC which is represented by the field `IPv4 CIDR` and let's consider it as `10.0.0.0`. Trying with this DNS couldn't work as we assign an invalid DNS. After a bit more investigation, we found that aThe DNS server provided in the VPC environment is the base of the VPC network range plus 2, so this way it will be => `10.0.0.2`, or we can use a generic one `169.254.169.253`.

**Just a reminder**

---

### > (0 to 255 inclusive), of which one is the network address (.0) and the other is the network broadcast address (.255).

This way, if we check if our client recognizes the DNS, we run:

```
vagrant@manager:~$ nslookup 172.*.*.2
2.0.31.172.in-addr.arpa name = ip-172-*-*-2.us-east-2.compute.internal.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

vagrant@manager:~$
```

We also run `dig` for the API Endpoint hostname to check the returned IPs. In this case, it should return 3 IPs, 1 for each subnet we associated with the endpoint.

```
vagrant@manager:~$ dig pwcc7wokgi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.9-Ubuntu <<>> pwcc7wokgi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com        
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17511
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pwcc7wokgi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.        IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:pwcc7wokgi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 4 IN CNAME 
execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 4 IN A     172.*.*.*
execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 4 IN A     172.*.*.*
execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. 4 IN A     172.*.*.*

;; Query time: 116 msec;; SERVER: 169.254.169.253#53(169.254.169.253);; WHEN: Tue Oct 22 17:04:35 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 137

vagrant@manager:~$
```

---

**2. Forwarding DNS to OpenVPN client**

To do so we have to add the following lines in the server configuration file.

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 169.254.169.253"
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.*.*.2"
```

The first line it's necessary not only in the case of DNS forwarding but to redirect all the traffic coming from the agent to go through the server.

The lines with `dhcp-option DNS` correspond to the DNSs we want to add to the client, 1 of them would be sufficient.

**2.1 Issues**

We faced some issues when the client could not get updated by the server or by the client itself. the DNS config. file `/etc/resolv.conf` got overwritten always by the default value:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

which is not our case. after some debugging we found that:

1. **We didn't have `resolveconf` library installed as it's essential for `OpenVPN` when forwarding DNSs.** `OpenVPN` uses two configuration file which uses the script `/sbin/resolveconf` to override the file `/etc/resolv.conf` when connecting or disconnecting from the VPN if needed.

In the client config. file

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

2. **`dnsmasq` also could override `/etc/resolv.conf` by default values - `Not a fixed case`**
   In our case, I needed to disable `dnsmasq` when connecting to the VPN so OpenVPN could not forward the DNSs as `/etc/resolv.conf` always overwritten it.
3. **It's recommended to restart `network-manager` if changes are made to `dnsmasq`.**

---

**Valid Log Message**

```
Tue Oct 22 17:17:16 2019 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 169.254.169.253,dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.2,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'

dhcp-option DNS 169.254.169.253
dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.2
```

Kind regards,

Rshad